# Full font hinting not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fonts, 18.04, antialiasing

It seems that full font hinting doesn't work in 18.04.

Due to low resolution laptop screens, I prefer the fonts with full hinting and grayscale antialiasing.

Changing the font hinting from medium to full seem to have no effect whatsoever.

[Here's how fonts look in Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOSzA.png), sharp and thin.

[and here's how they look in Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I63XD.png), thick and blurry.

I tried the following:

1. Changing the settings using Gnome Tweak Tool as shown in screenshot.
2. Copying `10-antialias.conf`, `10-no-sub-pixel.conf` and `10-hinting-full.conf` from `/etc/fonts/config.avail/` to `/etc/fonts/config.d/` and deleting the conflicting files in `config.d/`.
3. Putting this [fonts.conf](https://pastebin.com/bCzeJVvD) in `~/.config/fontsconfig/`.

But nothing worked.

Anybody else having the same problem? Any suggested solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a [solution to the problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype/+bug/1722508/comments/36) linked to in [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8gqrjn/ubuntu_1804_font_rendering_how_to_make_fonts_look/) post.

Add the following line to `/etc/environment` as root:

`FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35 cff:no-stem-darkening=1 autofitter:warping=1"`

Then restart the XServer (Xorg or XWayland) or reboot.

[It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5TJ6.png).

Comment: It's different, but for me is still ugly!

Comment: This is not v35 hinting engine at rhe screenshot named "it works". You can still compare fonts in chrome between 18.04 and 16.04. You will find plethora of diffs.

Comment: @uptoyou still, this is the best solution after those updates. Without full hinting, some people like me, find it blurred to read.

Comment: @OrhanG.Hafif i'm totally agree, but due to extremely lazy freetype evolution  (consider the fact that cleartype patents expiration didn't help freetype to qualitatively integrate their solutions) i ended up with HiDPI display, that solves almost all font's rendering issues.

Comment: And I'm still crying in front of a FHD display :D I'll buy one.