# Full font hinting for urxvt in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 18.04, graphics, fonts, 19.04, rxvt

I'm running 19.04 and I followed [Full font hinting not working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030041/full-font-hinting-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/1034399#1034399) to enable full font hinting. It works for graphical applications such as Chromium, but not my terminal (urxvt). How do I enable full font hinting for urxvt?

**Edit:**

Here is a side-by-side screenshot of urxvt (left) vs. emacs (right). emacs' font is slightly crisper. I'll admit the difference doesn't look that impressive, but at work I use a 4K monitor with the resolution set to 1920x1080, and for whatever reason the difference is much more pronounced.

[image: Screenshot]

Here are the contents of my `~/.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.foreground: #F2F2F2
URxvt.background: #000000
URxvt.font: xft:Monospace:size=15
URxvt.perl-ext-common: selection-to-clipboard,font-size
URxvt.font-size.step: 1
URxvt.keysym.C-equal: perl:font-size:increase

/* stop Ctrl-Shift from entering ISO 14755 mode */
URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false

/* font-size plugin from https://github.com/majutsushi/urxvt-font-size */
```

Comment: Can you include a side-by-side image of Chromium and urxvt?

Comment: And what do you have in *~/.Xresources*?

Comment: I edited my question to include the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

Full font hinting is done with lines like `Xft*hintstyle: hintfull` and `Xft*hinting: true`. They can be added to your `~/.Xdefaults` file.  Here are some lines in mine:

```
Xft*dpi: 82
Xft*antialias: true
Xft*hinting: true
Xft*rgba: rgb
Xft*autohint: false
Xft*hintstyle: hintfull
Xft*lcdfilter: lcddefault

URxvt*letterSpace: -2
```

There are many things that you can add like also choosing different fonts, etc.  You can play around with the settings till you get something you like.  Everybody's different.:

```
URxvt.intensityStyles: false
URxvt.allow_bold: false
URxvt.font: xft:Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular:pixelsize=17
URxvt.boldFont: xft:Ubuntu Mono:style=Bold:pixelsize=17  
URxvt.saveLines: 8192
```

After you launch `urxvt` it should look something like the following:

[image]

Hope this helps (some)!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out tomorrow and report the results.

Comment: @jth These lines could also be added to your `~/.Xresources`.  I've only used the `~/.Xdefaults` but I don't think it matters as I think they both load just fine.